# uniroot: error in f(lower, ...): argument " " is missing, with no default

Tags: r

Designing a function to calculate yield to maturity on a bond, but keep getting:

> Error in f(lower, ...) : 
>     argument "coupon_rate" is missing, with no default

Inputs:

- face_value: 1000
- coupon_rate: 0.1
- price: 101
- no_comp: 1
- tenure: 3

I have no idea what to adjust to rectify this. Thoughts?

Full code:

```
ytm <- function(face_value, coupon_rate, price, no_comp, tenure) {
  bval <- function(i, face_value, coupon_rate, price, no_comp, tenure, t=seq(along = cf)) {
    coupon_payment = face_value * coupon_rate
    cf <-  c(-face_value*(price/100),rep(c(coupon_payment), (no_comp * tenure -1)), face_value + coupon_payment)
    sum(cf / (1 + i)^t)
  }
  coupon_payment = face_value * coupon_rate
  cf <-  c(-face_value*(price/100),rep(c(coupon_payment), (no_comp * tenure -1)), face_value + coupon_payment)
  uniroot(ytm, interval=c(0, 20))$root
}

ytm(1000, 0.1, 101, 1, 3)
```

Comment: please provide some sample input

Comment: It's in the function call at the end of the code.

Comment: `uniroot(ytm, interval=c(0, 20))` needs arguments for `ytm`. Something like `uniroot(ytm,face_value, coupon_rate, price, no_comp, tenure, interval=c(0, 20))`.